# Domain Used in the past will affect Current SEO Project

Tags: seo

I am doing SEO of an domain, the domain is 16 years old and used by same person for multiple businesses in the past. Currently it is using for a business from last 5 years. The company is in the field of Training and certification for IT professionals. The businesses attached with the domain in the past will affect the current SEO project?

Comment: Sorry but this question has been asked several times already on Pro Webmasters in [various forms](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=purchase+domain+[seo]+is%3Aquestion), to avoid further disappointment please visit our help centre.

Answer (score 0):

It can affect, most of experts will advice to use old domain in prefer to new domain from SEO point of view. Yes domain age is a crucial factor and can provide your website a competitive edge in search results. But before you start using an old domain, here are couple of points you need to check carefully.

1. Online reputation of that domain name
2. is that domain penalize by Google or not

Comment: `3. Relevancy... ` Does the domain have revelant links otherwise they can become toxic... regardless of domain age and online reputation.

Comment: Its same if i buy a domain that have toxic links, I believe it should have been penalized by Google. Rest lets suppose if I have buy a old domain for which peoples have already made the trolls or put the negative reviews, then how can I survive in the online world. So ignoring online reputation will be a huge mistake

Comment: your missing my point... if a site with good links can have a negative impact... because if you buy a site that has links from sites about CATS, and you want to tell IT stuff, well that's not going to help, is it...